# Closing as duplicate

Tags: support, close-reasons, exact-duplicates

[Question A](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/regular-expression-for-phone-numbers) is a clear duplicate of
[Question B](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16717/regular-expression-for-language-of-phone-numbers), which has already been put on hold. (OK, at least A has responded to the "What did you try?" type questions.)  However, if you try to close Question A for being a duplicate of B, this is forbidden because "The question [B] does not have an upvoted or accepted answer".

Why is this a reason for refusing to close a question?  Why is it reasonable to have two copies of a question that hasn't been answered but not to have two copies of a question taht *has* been answered? The first time it was posted, it was not answered because it was inappropriate for the site.  The second time it was posted, it was still inappropriate for the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicates are probably only supposed to be maintained for SE-good questions.

I just closed A for the same reasons as B, which is a reasonable way to handle such cases.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose the only reason you'd *need* to use "duplicate" as a reason is if the question is good; for questions where the other one was closed, you can duplicate the reason for closing that one. On the other hand, suppose you ask a great question that's really difficult and nobody answers. Six months later, I ask the same thing but now we can't close my question as a dup.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I don't think you should repost the same question. Edits or, better yet, bounties bounce the question to the top, too.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to mention in my scenario that I didn't know the question had already been posted. (And, yes, of course I should check but people often don't.)